# strange thing in concatenation verilog

Tags: verilog

I have a module in `verilog` which gets two 64-bit numbers. These numbers are random. The strange thing is that when I debug it, `fa` is correct and starts with 1, but `fb` unexpectedly starts with 0.

What is wrong with it?

```
module adder(sum,a, b);
   input [63:0]   a;
   input [63:0] b;
   reg one;
output  reg [63:0] sum;
   reg [63:0] fa,fb;

    always @(a or b) begin
      one=1'b1;
    
      fb={one,b[51:0],12'b0};
      fa={one,a[51:0],12'b0};
      sum=64'b1;
    end
  endmodule
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bit width mismatch in this assignment:

```
fb={one,b[51:0],12'b0};
```

The left-hand side (LHS) is 64 bits wide, but the right-hand side (RHS) is 65 bits wide.

LHS:

- `fb` is 64 bits wide [63:0].

RHS:

- `one` is 1 bit wide
- `b[51:0]` is 52 bits wide
- `12'b0` is 12 bits wide

(1+52+12=65)

`one` is ignored because fb[11:0]=12'b0 and fb[63:12]=b[51:0].  Therefore, if b[51]=0, then fb[63]=0.

The same is true for `fa`.